# Switch Accessibility issue with recycler view and selection tracker

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, accessibility

We have a Recyclerview implemented with Selection Tracker for single mode selection in our application. It is working as expected in normal mode. The issue is with Switch Access mode. I am not able to navigate through each items in the recyclerview.

I can work around the above issue by enabling Point Scanning in the Switch access settings and select the desired item. But when I tried to select the item , the selection is not working. Basically observer added to the selection tracker to observe selection changes is not triggered.

Is there any special handling required for Switch Accessbility when we user recyclwer view + selection tracker ?

Note: I know if we add "Clickable= true" for the row layout, items in the recycler view get focus and navigate through the items. But the issue  with that approach is , there is no click listener added to the row layout for the selection.  It is handled through Selection tracker.